# 80's SF TV show where people are underground and cans have generic labels like MEAT

Tags: story-identification, tv

Anyone remember an 80's possibly early 90's show, seemed like it would be post-apocalyptic show, where people are underground buying food.  The cans were all generic, white labels with black writing MEAT.  I can remember the kid asking the mom, what kind of meat?  I want to say the dad in the show looked like the dude from [*V*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(TV_series)), the TV series, but I don't think it was *V*.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: By "looked like the dude from V," do you mean he wore a Guy Fawkes mask?

Comment: Or do you mean V, the tv-show about alien invaders?

Comment: Yes V, the 80's tv show about alien invaders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be *[Otherworld](https://friday87central.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/otherworld/)* from 1985?

> We all have a sense of home.  It’s where we feel safe, where we feel comfortable, where we know we can center ourselves and be who we really are, and always be accepted.  Or, at least, that’s the hope of most of us, and the reality for many.  But for the Sterling family, a 1985 vacation outing to the Great Pyramid of Giza turned that whole idea upside-down, and for them, home suddenly became some Otherworld.
>
> How it happened isn’t really that important.  Something about a rare once-every-ten-thousand-year planetary alignment, and being stuck in the Great Pyramid of Giza (by some crooked sightseeing guide who ducked and ran the minute the walls started shaking).  The important part is, by the end of the first act, you know this:  The Sterling family (father Hal, mother June, older teenage boy Trace, slightly younger teen girl Gina, and youngest son Smith) have all been transported to who-knows-where via some green misty vortex.  By the end of the second act, in the midst of trying to get help to figure out where they are, they’ve accidentally assaulted a vindictive military type named Kroll.  They’ve also taken his rather unique crystal, which is used to access all sorts of computers and such.  More importantly, the crystal is used to help cross the “Forbidden Zones” that have been set up to separate different groups of people to keep them tranquil, unique, and easier to control (at least from the military point of view).  In other words, in no time at all, they’ve officially gone from Egyptian sightseers to militant rabble-rousers, a threat to the peace in an unfamiliar new world, and have the worst of the military brass as their personal enemy… and all they essentially did was stop and ask for directions.

...

> It’s not all that different from our world, although the **cans of food are generically labeled “meat”** and “good food”; and the social studies class teaches that there were “77 different territorial capitals” before military unification, including the world headquarters, Imar.

### The Opening of the Show

I found it by searching for `tv show cans "labeled meat"`

Comment: Yes! That's it thank you!!!

Comment: The "Bad guy" was played by Jonathan Banks, who would later play Mike on "Breaking Bad" and "Better Call Saul".